# React controlled inputs

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the error "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)" however, I don't see how my inputs are uncontrolled from the start

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Inp = ({n, val, ud}) => {
    return <input type="text" value={val} name={n} onChange={ud} />
}

export function Proof(props) {

let groupId = props.match.params.groupId
const [val, setVal] = useState({})


if (val.length === 0) {
    return 'loading'
}

let ud = (event) => {
    setVal({
        ...val,
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
}  

return <div>
    <h2>Head</h2>

    <Inp n={'name'} id={0} val={val['name']} ud={ud} />
    <Inp n={'email'} id={1} val={val['email']}  ud={ud} />
    <p key={'un0'}>{val['email']}</p>
    <p key={'un1'}>{val['name']}</p>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your initial state is just an empty object. This means that `val['name']` and `val['email']` are `undefined` initially.

The warning is basically saying, "My value wasn't previously defined, but now it is. So I'm switching from uncontrolled to controlled."

Instead change your default state to include the keys you need with an empty string as its default. This will remove the warning

```
const [val, setVal] = useState({name: '', email: ''})
```